# Can I include modules "sideways" in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to split a Rust program into multiple files, but the use of `mod` doesn't see to allow me to reference files in the same directory from files other than `main.rs`.

For example, if I have `main.rs`, `game.rs`, and `matrix.rs` in the same folder, I can reference structs/functions from `game.rs` or `matrix.rs` in `main.rs` with a `mod game;` or `mod matrix;`. I can't, however, reference `matrix.rs` from `game.rs` with a statement like `mod matrix`.

I've looked at several resources and all of them only have modules structures like trees that don't reference each other. Is it possible to use structs/functions from files in each other in Rust, or is that against the rules? If so, why doesn't Rust let you do that?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22597760/994206). This is also covered in [the tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/book/crates-and-modules.html)

Comment: https://fasterthanli.me/articles/rust-modules-vs-files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mod` is *module declaration*. This directive declares a module and all of its contents. It just so happens that these contents may be located in another file. So this:

```
mod game;
mod matrix;
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
mod game {
    // game.rs contents
}

mod matrix {
    // matrix.rs contents
}
```

Naturally, since `mod` is a declaration of a module, you can't do it multiple times for the same module. That is, you can try and write something like

```
mod game {
    mod matrix;
    ...
}

mod matrix;
```

but, as you can see, `matrix` and `game::matrix` are different modules, and naturally rustc requires different paths to their respective files, if they are external.

`use`, however, is *import declaration*. `use` declarations pull names from other modules for use in the current module. You can `use` any module and any public items from it any number of times from anywhere this module is accessible.

So, in order to reference `matrix` from `game` you need to `use` it:

```
// game.rs
use matrix;
```

Naturally, in order for this to work `matrix` should be declared with `mod` in the crate root.

As a side note, I personally think that the simplest way to understand Rust module system is to first forget that modules can be put in different files at all. That is, think as if a crate can only be defined in a single file. In Rust `mod` directives can have bodies and can nest, so nested `mod`s actually define the module system of a crate:

```
mod foo {
    mod bax {
        ...
    }
    mod baz {
        ...
    }
}
mod bar {
    mod qux {
        mod zux {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you only have a single file, you can easily see how `mod` and `use` directives would work, and relationship between modules should become clear.

And now you only need to add to the picture the fact that if a module is declared without a body, like in `mod name;`, its content is loaded either from `name.rs` or `name/mod.rs`, whatever is available. However, the full picture does not change in the slightest - these still are nested modules which can *always* be represented as a single source file with nested `mod` directives. In fact, `cargo rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty=normal` will print your crate in this form, after all modules in external source files are assembled into a single document. I suggest running this command on some crates with complex module structure to see how it looks in practice.

Comment: For me the comprehension of mod is equivalent to a C or Cpp #include directive with some search capabilities to look for either name/mod or name.rs, but I might have missed to subtleties.

Comment: @XavierT. the two major differences between C/C++ and Rust is, first, that a compilation unit in Rust is much larger than in C/C++ (a crate, which corresponds to one or more .rs files and one or more modules, vs. an object file, which corresponds to exactly one .c/.cpp file with textually included headers), and second, that in Rust modules actually provide namespaces and encapsulation, which is not true for C and only partially true for C++ (where namespaces do exist, but are not tied to compilation units and do not provide abstraction boundaries).

Comment: Ah yes, the namespacing is important too !