# Is `pub` meant to indicate public-to-crate or public-to-module?

Tags: rust, visibility, conventions

To make methods from a submodule public, you have to explicitly re-export them or else make the submodule itself public:

```
mod foo {
    mod bar {
        pub fn baz() {}
    }
    pub use self::bar::baz;
}
```

This seems to hint that `pub` is used to indicate a thing should be public just to a module (since you can choose not to do this)

But if you use a private type defined in the outer context, you get an error if you try and make a public function involving it public in the inner context even when it's *not* re-exported.

```
mod foo {
    struct Foo;

    mod bar {
        use super::Foo;

        pub fn baz(foo: Foo) {}
    }
}
```

results in

```
error[E0446]: private type `Foo` in public interface
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
2 |     struct Foo;
  |     - `Foo` declared as private
...
7 |         pub fn baz(foo: Foo) {}
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
```

What's the idiomatic way to use the `pub` keyword? Should it be reserved for things that are *actually* public or can it be used for internal modules?

Comment: Sounds like you want [How do I make an Rust item public within a crate, but private outside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41666235/155423)

Comment: `pub(crate)` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Note that you can fix the compilation error with `pub use super::Foo;`

Answer (score 2):

The reason your example fails to compile, is ultimately because the [RFC (136)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0136-no-privates-in-public.md#what-restrictions-apply-to-public-items) said so. (See also [issue 22261](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22261))

> #### What restrictions apply to public items?
>
> The rules for various kinds of public items are as follows:
>
> - If it is a `static` declaration, items referred to in its type must be public.
> - **If it is an `fn` declaration, items referred to in its trait bounds, argument types, and return type must be public.**
> - If it is a `struct` or `enum` declaration, items referred to in its trait bounds and in the types of its `pub` fields must be public.
> - If it is a `type` declaration, items referred to in its definition must be public.
> - If it is a `trait` declaration, items referred to in its super-traits, in the trait bounds of its type parameters, and in the signatures of its methods (see `fn` case above) must be public.

In short, `baz` is not allowed to be `pub` because it has an argument which is a private type. Thus, if `baz` is `pub` it would allow the parent `mod foo` to re-export `baz` by doing `pub use bar::baz;`. This is of course not allowed, and this is the reason why the example as a whole is illegal.

Some have previously mentioned that `pub fn baz` should be allowed, and instead to give a compile error in the event that the parent module re-exports it. However, that would require more complex static analysis to detect, and ultimately has not been done because the RFC defined that it is illegal.

---

`pub` specifies that the item is accessible by the parent module. If all module ancestors are `pub`, then that item is exported by the crate as a whole.

> The keyword `pub` makes any module, function, or data structure accessible from inside of external modules. The `pub` keyword may also be used in a `use` declaration to re-export an identifier from a namespace.
>
> – [Rust Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.pub.html)

> With the notion of an item being either public or private, Rust allows item accesses in two cases:
>
> 1. If an item is public, then it can be accessed externally from some module m if you can access all the item's ancestor modules from m. You can also potentially be able to name the item through re-exports. See below.
> 2. If an item is private, it may be accessed by the current module and its descendants.
>
> – [The Rust Reference - Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html)

Comment: I understand the mechanics of _how_ pub works. I'm confused about when I should use it.
Why does the compiler complain about private-type-in-public-interface in my example?

Comment: Note that I tagged this question with `conventions`

Comment: Alright, give me a minute, and I'll redo the answer :)