# Confused about rust modules

Tags: module, rust

I have three files in `src/`, like so:

lib.rs

```
pub mod first
```

first.rs

```
fn hello() {}
```

main.rs

```
pub mod lib
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `first`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:9
  |
1 | pub mod first;
  |         ^^^^^
  |
  = help: name the file either lib/first.rs or lib/first/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

Now, if I remove `pub mod lib` from `main.rs`, everything compiles fine.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files ?

Comment: Please don't name a module `lib`. That could create confusion, because `lib.rs` is the root of a library crate.

Comment: By removing `pub mod lib;` you effectively remove all the code, so the error disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help that compiler says is very meaningful. 
When you write `pub mod first;` inside of a `lib.rs` it checks for the `first.rs` file or `first` folder inside a `lib` folder and a `mod.rs` file.

Please note that `mod.rs` usages are changed with Rust 2018. [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#no-more-modrs)

> Now, if I remove  pub mod lib  from main.rs, everything compiles fine.

When you remove `pub mod lib;` from your main,

You basically say that this code will not be used in production therefore it is not needed to compile even. So basically the code will not included to compile.

This is why it works when you remove the `pub mod lib;`