# How do I use structs declared in other modules in main.rs?

Tags: rust

Here is the situation. I have a project named **project_name** and it has this file hierarchy:

```
project_name
|-- src
|   |-- main.rs
|   |-- lib.rs
|   `-- tree_node.rs
```

I declared struct **TreeNode** in tree_node.rs.

```
pub struct TreeNode { ... }
```

There is method using **TreeNode** in **lib.rs**:

```
mod tree_node;

use tree_node::TreeNode;

pub struct Solution {}

impl Solution {
    pub fn invert_tree(root: TreeNode) -> TreeNode { ... }
}
```

But when I try to use method **invert_tree** in **main.rs** like this:

```
use project_name::Solution;
use tree_node::TreeNode;

mod tree_node;

fn main() {
    let tree = TreeNode::new(1);
    let result = Solution::invert_tree(tree);
}
```

I got an error:

```
expected struct `project_name::tree_node::TreeNode`, found struct
`tree_node::TreeNode`
```

Maybe I use incorrectly term **method** but I hope the main point is clear. What is wrong?

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: declare the module `tree_node` only in the library root module (lib.rs), then use the library as a crate in main.rs to import its capabilities.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module

Comment: Maybe this question duplicates somehow others but I think the answer proposed by @orlp is much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.rs` and `lib.rs` are effectively different crates that are compiled separately, and so `mod` creates separate modules for each when using in both `lib` and `main`. Generally you want to only use `mod` in `lib.rs` unless some module is only for private use of the application.

Therefore, replace `mod tree_node` from `main.rs` with `use project_name::tree_node::TreeNode;`.

In `lib.rs` you must change `mod tree_node` to `pub mod tree_node`, or `pub(crate) mod tree_node` if it's only intended for this crate and not outside users.

Comment: or else one can declare `TreeNode` in the lib.rs  as: `pub use tree_node::TreeNode;` if only wants to expose `TreeNode` from the inner module.